# How to add values to a PPTX using open XML SDK C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, powerpoint, openxml

Here is my requirement: 
I have a PPTX template with me. I used OPEN XML SDK's reflect code option to obtain the c# code. Now my requirement is to add values to the template from a SQL Server Database. It would be great if you can help me out with this ?

I am breaking my head over this! If not SQL Server database insertion can some one tell me how I can edit the XML document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution would be, making your own simple notation for strings you can replace, like `[CompanyName]`. Because pptx files are only zip files, you can open them in your program and parsing all slide1.xml files and replacing the placeholders with the text you need. Than save every thing and make a zip again.

Ok, here is a step by step solution:

1. Open the Zip-File in memory, using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), [SharpCompress](https://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/) or [SevenZipSharp](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/)
2. In the zip are files under: `~ppt/slideLayouts`, `~ppt/slideMasters` and `~ppt/slides` (The slides has numbers like: (slide1.xml, slide2.xml, ...)
3. Open every file in the folder and replace your tags with your values. `[CompanyName] --> Microsoft Inc.`
4. Save everything with the same structure as `.pptx` again.
5. Be happy

The header of the methode which do your tastks could look like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provide some power point helper methods
/// </summary>
public class PowerPointHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Prepare PPTX-File
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pptx">Byte-Array instance, containing the PPTX file</param>
    /// <param name="textToReplace">KeyValue Pairs which will be replaced in the PPTX</param>
    /// <returns>byte array containing the</returns>
    public byte[] PreparePPTX(byte[] pptx, IDictionary<string, string> textToReplace)
    {
        if (pptx == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("pptx");
        }

        byte[] returnValue = pptx;

        if (textToReplace != null)
        {
            // ...
            // ...
            // ...
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

**Solution 1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        public const string documentRelationshipType = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> toReplace = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            toReplace.Add("Sample2", "Sample - Text!");
            toReplace.Add("Sample3", "Sample 3 - Text!");

            using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open("C:\\Users\\beggers\\Desktop\\Test.pptx", true))
            {
                // Get the presentation part of the presentation document.
                PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;

                // Verify that the presentation part and presentation exist.
                if (presentationPart != null && presentationPart.Presentation != null)
                {
                    // Get the Presentation object from the presentation part.
                    Presentation presentation = presentationPart.Presentation;

                    // Verify that the slide ID list exists.
                    if (presentation.SlideIdList != null)
                    {
                        int slideNo = 1;

                        foreach (var slideId in presentation.SlideIdList.Elements<SlideId>())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Slide number: {0}", slideNo);
                            SlidePart slidePart = presentationPart.GetPartById(slideId.RelationshipId) as SlidePart;

                            ShapeTree tree = slidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree;
                            foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape shape in tree.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape>())
                            {
                                // Run through all the paragraphs in the document
                                foreach (Paragraph paragraph in shape.Descendants().OfType<Paragraph>())
                                {
                                    foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run run in paragraph.Elements<Run>())
                                    {
                                        foreach (var kvp in toReplace)
                                        {
                                            if (run.Text.InnerText.Contains(kvp.Key))
                                            {
                                                run.Text = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text(kvp.Value);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            slideNo++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Solution 1 need `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` to be referenced.

Comment: Hey. Are you free right now ? I have a doubt and I am currently working. Your help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: @ShashankSuresh what is your problem?

Comment: Below are the action items that I have carried out.
1. Created a PPTX with one slide and 1 text box.
2. Filled the text box with some random value.
3. Using the below vb.net code and LINQ, I can navigate through the XML file search for the ID and then update the text box with the value of my choice.
4. The problem here is when I try to re-create it to c#. 


Can you help me out with it ?

Comment: @ShashankSuresh what do you mean with below?

Comment: How do i send you the code ? Can you send me your email ID or something ? I would like to send you both the VB .net and C# code.

Comment: @ShashankSuresh use some upload website and send me your code over that.

Comment: Can you check here ? http://jsfiddle.net/htquamh4/

I have posted the vb .net on the left panel and the c# on the right. The c# is actually erring out with weird issues. vb .net works like a charm.

Comment: So the error is very simple. When I use the vb .net code, we use LINQ to query through the XML document to get the ID of the XElement "<p:sldIdLst>.<p:sldId>". This will give us the relationship ID of "slide1.xml" with which we can edit the "slide1.xml" and replace contents of the text box. 

Where as in the c# code, I am unable to get the ID of "<p:sldIdLst>.<p:sldId>" hence I get into a different xml file. Can you please check and correct the code ?

Comment: Did you get the PPTX file ?

Comment: @ShashankSuresh i added a more straight forward solution for your problem to my answer. Maybe this works for you. Please check the code and tell me if it works. The part with the `Paragraph` is only an example, you have to change it. so it fit to your needs. :)

Comment: I have no words to thank you. The code works perfectly. I am super happy. Thanks again for your active replies and help.

I have one doubt with regards to the below code:

            IDictionary<string, string> toReplace = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            toReplace.Add("Sample2", "Sample - Text!");
            toReplace.Add("Sample3", "Sample 3 - Text!");


If I am not wrong - "Sample2" and "Sample3" refers to the text right ?
If thats the case, then we are searching for a word in the PPTX file and we are replacing it. But what happens if I want to insert values from a SQL DB?

Comment: @ShashankSuresh do you can load the values in the dictionary and replace them?

Comment: That sounds good. Thanks ! One silly questions. In the code that you have given, what does "Sample2" and "Sample3" refer to ? Does it refer to the text in the PPTX or does it refer to an element name in the XML ?

Comment: It refers to a paragraph, that means simple text. But when you change it from `Paragraph` to anything else, you could use any control which is available in pptx.

Comment: Also one more doubt. How can I specify to which slide the change has to be done ? I have two slides and I want to make changes to the second one ? Does the code you gave above have that specification ? It would be great if you can add it as well ! I am actually overjoyed by your help. YOU ARE THE BEST. :-)

Comment: Please reply when ever you can. No rush :).
 Re-iterating the question. How do I mention the SLIDE number as I have my requirement to insert values in many slides ! Thanks you! Have a great day!

Comment: @ShashankSuresh this should be very simple. Added it to the solution 1 code.

Comment: I have been working on this for quite some time and it has been great. I found that if I have a about 20+ values to be filled in each slide , it becomes a pretty tedious task. Also, I tried digging a bit deeper and found that we can literally iterate through the XML nodes and elements and assign values. For example , I can search for "textbox 3" and change it's value to what ever the user likes. Is it possible you can help me out with this ?

Comment: Please reply when ever you get time :-) Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ShashankSuresh i am currently in a meeting, i will replay at the evening.

Comment: Sorry if I had disturbed you. Please take your time :-)

Comment: Hey @BendEg . Did you get a chance to look into my request ?

Comment: Please reply if you are online!

Comment: Hey buddy. I am still waiting on your reply. Sorry to keep bothering you! Thanks in advance!

Comment: How to download this updated pptx file to browser rather than save the original one?